# Print all Images in a ms access database

Tags: image, ms-access

I Have developed a reporting tool using ms access. It is composed of 10 forms which allows the user to input data. I also allow the user to upload images to the database(images are uploaded to image folder and the link is store in the database table).  The user could upload as many as 30 image files.
What i want to do is add another form which displays all the images the user has uploaded. Would this be possible in access i know in php you can use the mysql_num_rows function , just wondering is their a similar way to achieve this in access. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Basically when a form opens i want to run an Sql statement that retrieves all the images in the tables database and then shows the images on the form.

Comment: To begin with, there isn't a `num_rows()` function in PHP. Perhaps you refer to [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/pdo) or analogue functions—which I can't figure out what you need it for. Whatever, you should edit the question and explain what exactly you need help with. I can't believe you're stuck in *all* the steps involved.

Comment: I want to display all images together. that is if they would fit on one form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MS Access 2010:

\1. Create a continuous form, there is a wizard that will step you through. You can base the from on a table or query, a query is usually best. Ensure you include the field that holds the path to your image. You do not need to include the field with the path to the image on the form, it just needs to be part of the recordset.

\2. Add an image control

[image: image control]

\3. Set the control source for the image control to the name of the field that holds the path to the image.

[image: image control properties]

\4. View the form.

[image: image control form]

**The continuous form can be a subform**

[image: image control and subform]

Comment: Hi Remou , thanks for your help , seems to be what i'm looking for i'll give it a go and get back to you thanks